# Compactification of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness, complex-geometry

I want to look at compactification of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. There is a hypothesis that it is a complex projective space: $$\mathbb{CP}^n = \mathbb{C}^n + \mathbb{CP}^{n-1}_{\infty}$$
where $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}_{\infty}$  are some "infinity" points. For example, for $\mathbb{C}$ the compactification is well known Riemann Sphere: $$\mathbb{CP}^1 = \mathbb{C} + \lbrace{\infty\rbrace}$$
Firstly, I need to describe $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}_{\infty}$. Then, I want to introduce a metric on this space. By analogy, I can build a sphere $S^{2n+1}$ and consider complex lines, intersecting  sphere, and then introduce a metric as the distance between the circles generated by this intersection. I find the Fubini-Study metric. Why do I need a metric? I want to show that what came out is really a compact. How can I prove that $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is compact?

Thank you for advance for your help and explanations!

Comment: For the first part atleast, If you're looking for a 1 point compactification then $\mathbb{C}^n\cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and adding a point in infinity gives you the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{2n}$.

Comment: There isn't just one compactification of $\mathbb{C}^n.$ For example, you can always open point compactify a topological space by adding in an abstract point p, and saying sets are open if they are open in the original space, or they contain p, and their complement in the original space is compact. So you can one point compactify $\mathbb{C}^n.$ However, $\mathbb{C}^n$ is also homeomorhpic to an open ball, which you can compactify by adding in its boundary, hence you can compactiy $\mathbb{C}^n$ by adding in uncountable many points.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Melody!